# "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'docs' was called on null" Error Flutter Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I'm getting the error "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'docs' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried Calling: docs" whenever I try to use `.orderby("POST_ID", descending: true`. If someone has an answer to why I'm getting this error and how to fix it please help!
Here is my code:

```
          Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100.0),
          child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("Cities")
                  .doc(globals.selectedCity)
                  .collection("Posts")
                  .orderBy("POST_ID", descending: true)
                  .where("Category", isEqualTo: globals.selectedCategory)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, postSnapshot) {
                return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: postSnapshot.data.docs.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    switch (postSnapshot.data.docs[index]["Type"]) {
                      case "Image":
                        return new ImageCard(
                          imageLink: postSnapshot.data.docs[index]
                              ["ImageLink"],
                          imageDescription: postSnapshot.data.docs[index]
                              ["ImageDescription"],
                          posterName: postSnapshot.data.docs[index]
                              ["PosterName"],
                        );
                        break;

                      case "Text":
                        return new TextCard(
                          postText: postSnapshot.data.docs[index]
                              ["PostText"],
                          posterName: postSnapshot.data.docs[index]
                              ["PosterName"],
                        );
                        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```dart
    (postSnapshot.data.docs[index]["Type"])
```

You have to ensure first that you got the data from firestore. In your case when connection state is connecting or if snapshot has error you invoke `docs` on null object. Consider building widget tree with checks like this:

```dart
    class UserInformation extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CollectionReference users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');

    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: users.snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text('Something went wrong');
        }

        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Text("Loading");
        }

        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document.data()['full_name']),
              subtitle: new Text(document.data()['company']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So I did that but it's still not ordering. It just spits out the "Something went wrong" text.

Comment: You dont have `Permission denied` line in your debug console right?

Comment: And check that you are not passing null in globals.selectedCategory and globals.selectedCity

Comment: Yeah, no Permission denied error and globals.selectedCategory and globals.selectedCity both have values. This only happens when ordering the snapshot. If the snapshot is not ordered it works fine.